# make -j across PBS nodes

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, pbs

I would like run parallel tasks with `make -j` and have those tasks be distributed across [PBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System) nodes. The solution I am looking for is similar to the Slurm Makefile [here](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2014/09/parallelizing-gnu-make-4-in-slurm.html) except that my admin only allows me to run one job at a time, so I cannot set `SHELL=qsub`, for example.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this is possible. I'm guessing that it isn't, at this point, but I like the concept.

Comment: I think it's possible from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203215/customize-shell-in-makefile-set-shell-my-shell-sh/40203267?noredirect=1#comment67680958_40203267 though I no longer have access to a PBS cluster. If someone else has tried it and it works for them, I will upvote and accept.